# Radial Basis Functions Interpolation

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, interpolation, radial-basis-functions

$
\let\oldcdot\cdot
\renewcommand{\cdot}{\!\oldcdot\!}
\newcommand{\e}{\varepsilon}
\renewcommand{\p}{\varphi}
\renewcommand{\p}{\varphi}
\renewcommand{\vp}{\vec{\boldsymbol\p}(x)}
\newcommand{\P}{\boldsymbol \varPhi}
\newcommand{\O}{\boldsymbol \varOmega}
\newcommand{\x}{\vec{\boldsymbol{x}}}
\newcommand{\y}{\vec{\boldsymbol{y}}}
\newcommand{\f}{\vec{\boldsymbol{f}}}
\newcommand{\a}{\vec{\boldsymbol{\alpha}}}
$
Given two set of points   $\,\x = \left\{x _i \right\}_{i=1}^{n},\ \; \y = \left\{y _i \right\}_{i=1}^{n}\,$ in domain $\,\O\in \mathbb R^d$ and a target function $\,f:\O\to\mathbb R\,$ I need to approximate  $\,f\,$ by [Radial Basis Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function#Approximation) with reasonable accuracy.

> **Description of approximation process**:
>  Choose generating function $\,\p:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R\,$  and define  $\,\p_i(x) = \p\big(\e\left\| x_i - x\right\|\big)$, so we can approximate $\,f(x) \approx \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i \p_i(x).$  Denote vector of coefficients $\,\a = \{ \alpha_i\}_{i=1}^{n},\,$ interpolation matrix $\, \P = \{ \p_i(\,y_j\,)\}_{i,j = 1}^{n},\,$   estimation vector $\,\vp = \{ \p_i\left(x\right)\}_{i = 1}^{n},\,$ and vector of values of $\,f\,$ at $\,\x\,$ as $\,\f =  f(\,\x\,).\,$  Then  we can write the RBF expansion of $\,f\,$ in the *matrix form*:  $\qquad \qquad \quad \f = \P \cdot \a \implies \a  = \P^{-1}\cdot\f \implies  f(x) \approx \vp \cdot \a  =  \vp \cdot \P^{-1}\cdot\f .$

I have troubles choosing optimal shape parameter $\e$, optimal distribution of RBF centers and optimal type of RBF.
To make things worse, the domain $\,\O\,$ is supposed to be general manifold.

Starting from the simple case of $1\mathrm{D}$ domain I cannot lower the accuracy of the approximation as the interpolation matrix $\P$  becomes increasingly ill-conditioned. 
Ultimately I need to be able to reconstruct not just function, but also its derivatives and more sophisticated differential operators, but I cannot even reach $10^{-3}$ order of error even for straightforward function reconstruction on a nice $1\mathrm{D}$ manifold like semicircle or straight  interval.

---

I would be very happy if someone could  advise me techniques which could help increase accuracy of RBF approximation and/or prevent condition number of $\P$ from decreasing too rapidly.

---

**PS** This is a follow-up on my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1350997/229317) about [RBF approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function#Approximation).

Comment: You may want to look into preconditioners for RBFs.

Comment: @Joel Could you provide a relevant reference, or elaborate on the preconditioning for RBFs?

Comment: I am busy right now, but I can look up some references in a couple of days.

Comment: so your question is how to choose the shape parameter?

Comment: @CharlieParker Indeed I am would like to know how to choose the shape parameter, but I am also asking more general question "What are techniques  (of any kind) for improving accuracy of RBF approximations?"

Comment: @Vlad honestly it seems like an open problem, but this paper (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.109.312&rep=rep1&type=pdf) seem to summarize what is known well. I also found this one useful though seems more theoretical (in the sense that they prove things) http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v51/que16.html, hope it helps, if you find anything more feel free to share it here please! :)